# gevent Import Error

Tags: python, django, volttron

It was working fine at first but when reinstalled to verify my process I get this error, all the requirements have been confirmed, and I have not changed the path of any file.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 705, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run
  File "/home/tinker/a/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/auth.py", line 147, in zap_loop
    time = gevent.core.time
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
2018-05-16T05:19:17Z <Greenlet "Greenlet-0" at 0xb436e360L: <bound method AuthService.zap_loop of <volttron.platform.auth.AuthService object at 0xb4371b30>>(<volttron.platform.vip.agent.core.Core object at 0)> failed with AttributeError

2018-05-16 05:19:17,340 () volttron.platform.main DEBUG: In-process VIP router bound to inproc://vip
2018-05-16 05:19:17,341 () volttron.platform.main DEBUG: Local VIP router bound to ipc://@/home/tinker/.volttron/run/vip.socket?domain=vip#bdc8ff59-e99b-4629-b6b7-df00ffc8cc44
2018-05-16 05:19:17,441 () volttron.platform.main DEBUG: protected topics file /home/tinker/.volttron/protected_topics.json
2018-05-16 05:19:17,497 () volttron.platform.main INFO: loading protected-topics file /home/tinker/.volttron/protected_topics.json
2018-05-16 05:19:17,498 () volttron.platform.main INFO: protected-topics file /home/tinker/.volttron/protected_topics.json loaded
2018-05-16 05:19:17,503 () volttron.platform.web INFO: Web server not started.
2018-05-16 05:19:17,505 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: unhandled exception in periodic callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tinker/a/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/core.py", line 124, in _loop
    method(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/tinker/a/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/heartbeat.py", line 160, in publish
    self.pubsub().publish('pubsub', topic, headers, message)
  File "/home/tinker/a/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/pubsub.py", line 396, in publish
    message=message, bus=bus)
  File "/home/tinker/a/BMEOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 303, in call
    request, result = self._dispatcher.call(method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/tinker/a/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 115, in call
    result = next(self._results)
  File "/home/tinker/a/BEMOSS/volttron/platform/vip/agent/results.py", line 85, in next
    result.ident = ident = '%s.%s' % (next(self._counter), hash(result))
AttributeError: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
2018-05-16 05:19:17,520 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: unhandled exception in periodic callback
```

Comment: Any update on the solution as I am facing a similar issue?

Comment: Not yet I believe its bug as we can see in the [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368744/error-while-running-the-bemoss-i-am-getting-attributeerror-gevent-event-asyn )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was caused due to the version change of gevent library, So after installing gevent == 1.2.2 the issue was solved.