# Error while running the bemoss, I am getting AttributeError: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'

Tags: python, cassandra, cassandra-3.0, volttron

```
File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 705, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run
File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/auth.py", line 147, in zap_loop
time = gevent.core.time
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'core'
2018-05-16T09:52:00Z <Greenlet "Greenlet-0" at 0x7f37102cd998: <bound 
method AuthService.zap_loop of <volttron.platform.auth.AuthService 
object at 0x7f3718630050>>(<volttron.platform.vip.agent.core.Core object at 0)> failed with AttributeError




 2018-05-16 15:22:06,815 wheel INFO: creating 
'/tmp/tmpPCrbeW/pkg/dist/bacnet_proxyagent-0.1-py2-none-any.whl' and adding '.' to it
2018-05-16 15:22:06,816 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxy/rough.py'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,816 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxy/__init__.py'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,817 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxy/agent.py'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,817 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,817 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/entry_points.txt'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,817 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/metadata.json'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,817 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/top_level.txt'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,817 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/WHEEL'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,818 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/METADATA'
2018-05-16 15:22:06,818 wheel INFO: adding 'bacnet_proxyagent-0.1.dist-info/RECORD'
clear: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
Unpacking to: /home/interview/.volttron/agents/cd699ad7-934b-4e78-8ff8-68ab3d54a592/bacnet_proxyagent-0.1
Installed /home/interview/.volttron/packaged/bacnet_proxyagent-0.1-py2-none-any.whl as cd699ad7-934b-4e78-8ff8-68ab3d54a592 bacnet_proxyagent-0.1
VOLTTRON_HOME=/home/interview/.volttron
clear: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
Unpacking to: /home/interview/.volttron/agents/b50a12ee-2602-4622-b943-f78380d450ae/VIPagent-3.0
 Installed /home/interview/.volttron/packaged/VIPagent-3.0-py2-none-any.whl as b50a12ee-2602-4622-b943-f78380d450ae VIPagent-3.0
 VOLTTRON_HOME=/home/interview/.volttron
 clear: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'  
 Unpacking to: /home/interview/.volttron/agents/69e82743-344f-4e82-a447-8fc5d26bcbb1/TSDagent-3.0
 Installed /home/interview/.volttron/packaged/TSDagent-3.0-py2-none-any.whl as 69e82743-344f-4e82-a447-8fc5d26bcbb1 TSDagent-3.0
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident' 
 start: error: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'



 File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/results.py", line 85, in next
  result.ident == '%s.%s' % (next(self._counter), hash(result))
  AttributeError: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
2018-05-16 16:00:00,128 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: unhandled exception in periodic callback
```

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/heartbeat.py", line 160, in publish
    self.pubsub().publish('pubsub', topic, headers, message)
       File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/pubsub.py", line 396, in publish
    message=message, bus=bus)

```
  File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 303, in call
request, result = self._dispatcher.call(method, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 115, in call
   result = next(self._results)
  File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/results.py", line 85, in next
   result.ident == '%s.%s' % (next(self._counter), hash(result))
 AttributeError: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
2018-05-16 16:03:00,133 () volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: unhandled exception in periodic callback
  Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/core.py", line 124, in _loop
method(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
     File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/heartbeat.py", line 160, in publish
self.pubsub().publish('pubsub', topic, headers, message)
    File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/pubsub.py", line 396, in publish
message=message, bus=bus)

  File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 303, in call
request, result = self._dispatcher.call(method, args, kwargs)
 File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 115, in call
   result = next(self._results)
 File "/home/interview/BEMOSS3.5/volttron/platform/vip/agent/results.py", line 85, in next
   result.ident == '%s.%s' % (next(self._counter), hash(result))
 AttributeError: 'gevent._event.AsyncResult' object has no attribute 'ident'
```

When I reinstalled BEMOSS3.5 I am getting these errors and server cannot be started.
I had removed all the files and configurations and then reinstalled but I am getting these error and can not resolve these errors. 
Can someone Help me on this issue.

Comment: What is a TSD agent?  When you say you removed all files, does that mean you removed VOLTTRON_HOME?

Comment: I have no idea about TSD agent. I had uninstalled BEMOSS 3.5 completely and installed it again. after installing when i tried to run BEMOSS I m facing these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the gevent and try installing gevent == 1.2.2.This might address the issue.